# WNet function doesn't work C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, wnet

I use VS 2012. I want to use finction WNetGetUser:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
char Name[255];
char Test[255];
DWORD size=255;
if (WNetGetUser(Test,Name,&size)==NO_ERROR)
{
    cout << Name << endl;
}
}
```

But I got error:**unresolved external symbol _WNetGetUserA@12 referenced in function _main**

How can I solve this problem?
Where can I find right header for including?

Comment: I cant find right header for including

Comment: It's not about a header, you need to link against the WNet library.

Comment: What I must do? Include wpr.lib?